# How to include a return statement when executing a Polly policy?

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic

Below is my code in C# Windows application, where connection with Oracle, FTP and Null Reference Exception are handled:

```
public Result Execute()
{
    Result result = null;
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;

    var retryTimes = 1000;
    var retryableErrorCodes = new[] { "ORA-03113", "ORA-03114", "ORA-12543",
        "ORA-12170", "ORA-12154", "ORA-12541", "ORA-12560", "ORA-03135",
        "Connection request timed out" };
    var retryExceptionError = new[] { "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" };

    RetryPolicy retryPolicyFTP = Policy
        .Handle<Xceed.Ftp.FtpInvalidStateException>().Or<Xceed.Ftp.FtpIOException>()
        .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    RetryPolicy retryPolicyOracle = Policy
        .Handle<OracleException>(ex => retryableErrorCodes.Any(errorCode => ex.Message.ToString().Contains(errorCode)))
        .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    RetryPolicy retryException = Policy
        .Handle<Exception>(ex => retryExceptionError.Any(errorCode => ex.Message.ToString().Contains(errorCode)))
        .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    Policy.Wrap(retryPolicyFTP, retryPolicyOracle, retryException).Execute(() =>
    {
        //few lines of C# Code like fetching details from Database
        if(some condition)
        {
            //Some Operations
            return new Result(ResultType.Failure, "This function has Failed");
        }
        if(some other condition)
        {
            //Some Operations
            return new Result(ResultType.Success, "This function is Successful");
        }
        //Some more lines of C# Code
    });
    return Result.Successful;
}
```

With this code, I cannot use `return` keyword in the middle of the function, because Polly framework does not allow it to do so.

Could you please suggest what is the better way of handling `return` keyword in the middle of the function?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Did you mean to put the `return Result.Successful` before the `});` on the line above?

Comment: There are return keywords inside `Policy.Wrap`. When you copy the same code in `Visual Studio` , then you would see to red squigglies for the return keywords inside `if` conditions. I would like to have an executable code with this `Policy.Wrap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Polly you can define decorators for methods and for functions.

In case of a method the retry policy should be defined like this:

```
RetryPolicy retryPolicyFTP = Policy
    .Handle<Xceed.Ftp.FtpInvalidStateException>().Or<Xceed.Ftp.FtpIOException>()
    .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

In case of a function the retry policy should be defined like this:

```
RetryPolicy<Result> retryPolicyFTP = Policy<Result>
    .Handle<Xceed.Ftp.FtpInvalidStateException>().Or<Xceed.Ftp.FtpIOException>()
    .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

You should spot here the `<Result>` parts on lhs and rhs as well.

---

With this knowledge your method could be rewritten like this:

```
public Result Execute()
{
    Result result = null;
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;

    var retryTimes = 1000;
    var retryableErrorCodes = new[] { "ORA-03113", "ORA-03114", "ORA-12543", "ORA-12170", "ORA-12154", "ORA-12541", "ORA-12560", "ORA-03135", "Connection request timed out" };
    var retryExceptionError = new[] { "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" };

    RetryPolicy<Result> retryPolicyFTP = Policy<Result>
        .Handle<Xceed.Ftp.FtpInvalidStateException>().Or<Xceed.Ftp.FtpIOException>()
        .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    RetryPolicy<Result> retryPolicyOracle = Policy<Result>
        .Handle<OracleException>(ex => retryableErrorCodes.Any(errorCode => ex.Message.ToString().Contains(errorCode)))
        .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    RetryPolicy<Result> retryException = Policy<Result>
        .Handle<Exception>(ex => retryExceptionError.Any(errorCode => ex.Message.ToString().Contains(errorCode)))
        .WaitAndRetry(retryTimes, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    Result res = Policy.Wrap(retryPolicyFTP, retryPolicyOracle, retryException).Execute(() =>
    {
        if (some condition)
        {
            return new Result(ResultType.Failure, "This function has Failed");
        }
        if (some other condition)
        {
            return new Result(ResultType.Success, "This function is Successful");
        }
        return Result.Successful;
    });
    return res;
}
```

Because your `Execute` has to return a `Result` that's why the `Result.Successful` could be moved inside the `Execute` block.

---

I would also suggest to separate strategy declaration and execution like this:

```
public Result Execute()
{
    ...

    var strategy = Policy.Wrap(retryPolicyFTP, retryPolicyOracle, retryException)
    return strategy.Execute(() =>
    {
        if (some condition)
        {
            return new Result(ResultType.Failure, "This function has Failed");
        }
        if (some other condition)
        {
            return new Result(ResultType.Success, "This function is Successful");
        }
        return Result.Successful;
    });
}
```